# Get Future as a String for use in Text Widget?

Tags: string, flutter, variables, dart, future

I've got the following future method which fetches a string from a PHP/Mysql database.

```
Future<String> getCount({ String audioid,}) async {
  final String pass = "";
  String  upDateUrl = "http://example.com;
  final response = await get(upDateUrl);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return response.body;
  }
  print(response.body);
}
```

Then I've got this variable at the top line of my build;

```
 var replycount = getCount(audioid: speakcraft.audioid);
```

When I try to access the String in a Text Widget;

```
Text(replycount.toString(),
```

I get this instead of the String I need;

```
Instance of 'Future<String>'
```

How do I get my database result as a String?